# Подключение библиотеки в Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Здравствуйте, скачал с github библиотеку itinero (https://github.com/itinero/routing), она в архиве zip, внутри никакого dll файла нет, подключить через References тоже не получается. Nuget в VS2008 не предусмотрен и его установка не увенчалась успехом. Подскажите пожалуйста, как же все-таки подключить itinero к моему проекту на c#, очень надо, спасибо.

Comment: А что в архиве, нам нужно догадаться самим, чтобы вопрос был интереснее?

Comment: А то мешает установить Visual Studio 2017 community edition? Она бесплатная.

Comment: У автора в архиве скорей всего исходный код библиотек, которые он скопировал с указанного GitHub. В таком случае его для начала нужно собрать, а уж затем добавлять в References созданную библиотеку.